# How to fill for the first time a SQL database with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, r, database, data-modeling, data-science

I have a general question regarding the method of how to fill a database for the first time. Actually, I work on "raw" datasets within R (dataframes that I've built to work and give insights quickly) but I now need to structure and load everything in a relational Database.

For the DB design, everything is OK (=> Conceptual, logical and 3NF). The result is a quite "complex" (it's all relative) data model with many junction tables and foreign keys within tables.

My question is : **Now, what is the easiest way for me to populate this DB ?**

My approach would be to generate a .csv for each table starting from my "raw" dataframes in R and then load them table per table in the DB. **Is it the good way to do it or do you have any easier method ?** . Another point is, **how to not struggle with FK constraints while populating ?**

Thank you very much for the answers. I realize it's very "methodological" questions but I can't find any tutorial/thread related

**Notes : I work with R (dplyr, etc.) and MySQL**

Comment: Tip: You may find more valuable info on the sister site, [*DBA Stack Exchange*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A serious [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database), such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) for example, will offer features for populating a large database.

## Bulk loading

Look for commands that read in external data to be loaded into a table with a matching field structure. The data moves directly from the OS’s file system file directly into the table. This is vastly faster than loading individual rows with the usual SQL `INSERT`. Such commands are not standardized, so you must look for the proprietary commands in your particular database engine.

In Postgres that would be the [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command.

## Temporarily disabling [referential-integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)

Look for commands that defer enforcing the foreign key relationship rules until after the data is loaded.

In Postgres, use [`SET CONSTRAINTS … DEFERRED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html) to not check constraints during each statement, and instead wait until the end of the transaction.

Alternatively, if your database lacks such a feature, as part of your mass import routine, you could delete your constraints before and then re-establish them after. But beware, this may affect all other transactions in all other database connections. If you know the database has no other users, then perhaps this is workable.

## Other issues

For other issues to consider, see the [*Populating a Database*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/populate.html) in the Postgres documentation (whether you use Postgres or not).

- Disable Autocommit
- Use `COPY` (for mass import, mentioned above)
- Remove Indexes
- Remove Foreign Key Constraints (mentioned above)
- Increase `maintenance_work_mem` (changing the memory allocation of your database engine)
- Increase max_wal_size (changing the configuration of your database engine’s write-ahead log)
- Disable WAL Archival and Streaming Replication (consider moving a copy of your database to replicant server(s) rather than letting replication move the mass data)
- Run ANALYZE Afterwards (remind your database engine to survey the new state of the data, for use by its query planner)

## Database migration

By the way, you will likely find a database migration tool helpful in creating the tables and columns, and possibly in loading the data. Consider tools such as [Flyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software)) or [Liquibase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquibase).

Comment: Thank you very much for your very complete answer @Basil